# Создать экземпляр lxml.html.document_fromstring() или lxml.etree.XML

Tags: html, python, xml, lxml

Здравствуйте, мне нужно обработать html документ.

Следующий код выдает ошибку.

```
from lxml import etree
import requests
import lxml.html as LH
from io import StringIO

def get_tree(url):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36'}
    result = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    return LH.document_fromstring(result.content.decode())

url = 'http://www.naturalnews.com/'
tree = get_tree(url)
```

Ошибка:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x85 in position 41101: invalid start byte
```

Помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте следующий вариант

```
from lxml import etree
import requests
import lxml.html as LH

def get_tree(url):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36'}
    result = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    return LH.fromstring(result.content)

url = 'http://www.naturalnews.com/'
tree = get_tree(url)

title = tree.cssselect("title")[0]
print(title.text)
```